# Incompatible types error in Java int from int[]

Tags: java

I'm coding to make a binary division by simply subtracting and keeping a counter but I get the Incompatible types error when I try to convert to binary and then divide it. Here's the code so far:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Divisao{

public static int[] subtrair(int[] bin1 , int[] bin2){

int[] result;
result = new int [bin1.length];

    for (int i = bin1.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
        boolean flag = false;

        if (bin1[i] - bin2[i] == 0){
            result[i] = 0;
        }
        else if (bin1[i] - bin2[i] == 1){
            result[i] = 1;
        }
        else{
            bin1[i-1]--;
            bin1[i] = bin1[i] + 2;
            i++;
        }
    }
return result;

}

public static int[] binary(int n)
{
    int[] bin = new int[16];
    int ctr = 15;
    int num = n;
    /** complemento de 2 para negativos **/
    if (n < 0)
        num = 65536 + n;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        bin[ctr--] = num % 2;
        num /= 2;
    }
    return bin;
}

public static int divide(int[] bin1,int[] bin2){
    int cont = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<bin2.length-1;i++){
            while(bin1[i]>bin2[i]){
                subtrair(bin1,bin2);
                cont++;
            }
        }
    return cont;
}



public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Algoritmo para divisão de binarios\n");
    Divisao d = new Divisao();

    /** Entrar dois números decimais **/
    System.out.println("Entre dois numeros decimais\n");
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    int[] result;

    try{
        n1 = scan.nextInt();
        n2 = scan.nextInt();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Por favor, entre um numero entre -2,147,483,648 e 2,147,483,647");
        return;
    }


        int[] b1 = binary(n1);
        int[] b2 = binary(n2);
        result = d.divide(b1, b2);



    System.out.println ("fodeu");       
}
}
```

when I compile it, it says that "b1" (the binary array from n1) is an INT and the parameter requires an INT[]

HEELP

Comment: What would be your guess as to what is wrong given that error statement? What is an `int`? What is an `int[]`?

Answer (score 3):

Your divide() function returns an int, not an array. You're trying to store it in an int[] array variable (result).

Answer (score 0):

The divide function returns an int and you are trying to store it in an int array you need to store it as an int.